# Jetpack compose: how to set intrinsic height as minimum, but expand to fill space?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to set it so that a TextField refuses to shrink past its intrinsic height (defined by `minLines`), but also grow to fill max height:

```
// context: this is inside of a Column that has fillMaxHeight on it
OutlinedTextField(
    // unrelated fields
    minLines = 26,
    modifier = Modifier
        //.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .weight(1f)
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
)
```

However, everything I've tried (setting `fillMaxHeight`, `weight(1f)`, using `requiredHeight` instead of `height`, etc) has issues. It seems like it's mutually exclusive: I can either set a minimum height based on intrinsic height *or* I can grow to fill the height (using weight seems to work for that, but not fillMaxHeight for some reason.

What is the proper way to have `IntrinsicSize` be the minimum, but grow to fill remaining space?

Comment: When you chain size modifiers first one is applied for height or width except requiredX modifiers, they force to their constraints even if it's outside of parent boundaries or Constraints. Modifier.width(100.dp).fillMaxWidth() results a Composable with 100.dp width instead of covering available space by parent. What does minlines property supposed to do? Is it by any chance maxLines?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this question correctly you want your TextField height to be one line tall then increases as user enters text. You can selectively change modifier using `Modifier.then()`

### Edit

As of jetpack compose 1.4.0-alpha02 `minLines` param is added to `OutlineTextField` and other text composables

```
@Composable
private fun Sample() {

    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Hello World")
    }

    var focused by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                text = it
            },
            minLines = 26,
            // unrelated fields
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .then(
                    if (focused) {
                        Modifier.wrapContentHeight()
                    } else Modifier.fillMaxHeight()
                )
                .onFocusChanged {
                    focused = it.isFocused
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what I meant-- I'd like it to (when the user lands on the screen) fill all available space. Then, when the soft keyboard is active (which adds inset padding), I'd like it to shrink *only* down to the 

Basically: default height should fill empty space in the screen, but minimum height should be derived from the intrinsic property of `minLines` (i.e., nothing can force it to shrink down smaller than that).

Comment: @Nathan minLines is added in 1.4.0-alpha02 you can check out code above if it fits your requirements